# How to make @Input type of the library component extendable in the app

Tags: angular, typescript, types, components

We have monorepo with library and app. Inside library we have  component that accepts Icon type which is union of all icon file names (see code below). Reason why didnt go with just string is we wanted to strongly type names so nobody by mistake will call icon that does not exist and in our storybook we can list all available icons.

```
const LIBRARY_ICONS = {
  edit: 'pen',
  view: 'eye',
  config: 'gear',
  error: 'error',
};
type Icon = keyof typeof LIBRARY_ICONS;

@Component({
  selector: 'ta-icon',
  templateUrl: './icon.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./icon.component.scss'],
})
export class IconComponent {
  constructor() {}

  @Input() icon: Icon;

  get svgPath() {
    const iconName = LIBRARY_ICONS[this.icon];
    return `assets/images/icons/${iconName}.svg`;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately that means that our library had full list of icons (shared and app specific). I would like to extend this design and move app specific icon names out of library into our app. That means I need ability for any application to extend type Icon into something like AppIcon type that is declared in app and has union with Icon type. This way we will have icon types that specific for the app.

```
const APP_ICONS = {
  chair: 'chair',
  ....more name-value pairs
};
type AppIcon = keyof typeof APP_ICONS | Icon;
```

But since icon component takes only Icon type as input Im not sure how to make it accept AppIcon.

Any ideas?

**Update**

I tried to make Icon component accept generic type that derived from Icon.

```
export class IconComponent <T extends Icon> {
  @Input() icon: T;
}
```

When I try using icon from my derived type AppIcon in template angular still doesnt like it :( Not sure how to use component with generic from template.
Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-icon-proto?file=src/app/models/app-icon.model.ts)